# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method despite the fact that there are no null values for the parameters being queried

Tags: asp.net, linq, model-view-controller

I get the following exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'OARRS_Staff.Dtos.SearchRequestDto get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

strangely if i drop `FirstOrDefault` I don't have this issue but I really only need the single record or `null`

```
var statuschange = _context.StateChanges
                    .Include(m => m.Staff)
                    .Where(m => m.statusID == searchRequestDto[c].statusID
                         && m.requestDetailID == searchRequestDto[c].requestDetailID)
                    .OrderByDescending(m => m.statusChangeID)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: also its the same if i use Single, or SingleOrDefault or First

Comment: Something is missing, post more of the stack trace.

Comment: If you remove `FirstOrDefault()` the query doesn't execute, hence no exception. Hint: `searchRequestDto[c].statusID` can't be translated into SQL. Put the values in variables first.

Comment: My guess is because searchRequestDto[c].statusID needs to be evaluated and cannot be included while running the expression.

Comment: @GertArnold seems putting the value in variables worked. Thanks